# How to migrate from Clearcase to Bluemix DevOps services?

Tags: ibm-cloud, rtc, devops, ibm-jazz

Understand [Bluemix DevOps](http://hub.jazz.net) is using Rational Team Concert behind the scenes. We are looking to migrate from an existing Clearcase repository to Bluemix DevOps and are looking for ways to migrate the repository including version history to Bluemix DevOps. What are our options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is based on RTC, the official way to start the migration would be with the [Rational Team Concert and Rational ClearCase integration cookbook](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Deployment/RationalTeamConcertAndRationalClearCaseIntegrationCookbook), and its [Rational ClearCase Bridge](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Deployment/RationalTeamConcertAndRationalClearCaseIntegrationCookbook#Rational_ClearCase_Bridge)

However, if BlueMix DevOps [works with git repos](https://hub.jazz.net/features/#githosting), don't forget to make sure the UCM components from ClearCase are not too big when they are translated into git repos as RTC components.